# Change root depending on whether a user is logged in or not without Devise on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use another root for my application when a user is already logged in but I don't know how to do it without Devise, we implemented all of the authentication's logic from scratch. We're using Rails 4.

Comment: If you built your own authentication why not just add a redirect to your auth method on login/logout?

Comment: What do you mean by root? Do you mean another handler for the root path?

Comment: I mean that for a logged in user root must be, for example "www.example.com/users/1", while for a user that is not logged in, for example "www.example.com"

Comment: If you want the `/` path to lead an authenticated user to `/users/1` you would need to redirect in whatever action handles the root path.

Comment: The problem is that if this user types in the address bar of his browser "www.example.com", he will reach the home page of the site while I want that he is automatically redirected to his profile page.

Answer (score 4):

In Devise there is a [`authenticated` routes helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/69bee06ceee6280b54304928bb6e55c5064abad8/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb) which lets you create routes which are only accessible to an authenticated user:

```
unauthenticated do
  root 'pages#home'
end

authenticated do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  resources :things
end
```

This is possible due to the fact that [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) actually does most of the heavy lifting when it comes to authentication and Warden lives on the rack layer.

Lets say you have a bare bones system on top of Warden. This is how you would create something similiar:

```
module ActionDispatch::Routing
  class Mapper
    def authenticated(&block)
      block.call if env['warden'].authenticated?  
    end

    def unauthenticated(&block)
      block.call if env['warden'].unauthenticated?  
    end
  end
end
```

You can replace `env['warden'].unauthenticated?` with whatever you have in your home rolled authentication system - but note that it has to work as Rack middleware. If your authentication system is some junk shoved into `ApplicationController` or a helper its not going work as that is far too late in the request cycle.